# Why doesn't javascript execute in .php file loaded with Ext.Ajax.Request?

Tags: ajax, extjs

I want to load .php files via ajax which execute ExtJS script as they load, which in turn modifies the existing ExtJS objects already present in the DOM.

However, I can't even get Javascript to execute from a page that is being loaded via `Ext.Ajax.request`. And no errors are showing up in the Firebug Net panel. The PHP code gets executed, but not the Javascript. When I call the page being loaded by itself in the browser, it executes the Javascript fine.

**How can I get Javascript to execute in pages loaded with Ext.Ajax.request?**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var menuItemStart = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'panelStart',
        title: 'Start',
        html: 'This is the start menu item.',
        cls:'menuItem'
    });

    var menuItemApplication = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'panelApplication',
        title: 'Application',
        html: 'this is the application page',
        cls:'menuItem'
    });

    var regionMenu = new Ext.Panel({
        region:'west',
        split:true,
        width: 210,
        layout:'accordion',
        layoutConfig:{
            animate:true
        },
        items: [ menuItemStart, menuItemApplication ]
    });

    var regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'contentArea',
        region: 'center',
        padding:'10',
        autoScroll: true,
        html: 'this is the content'
    });

    new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ regionMenu, regionContent ]
    });

    menuItemStart.header.on('click', function() {
       Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: 'content/view_start.php',
           success: function(objServerResponse) {
               regionContent.update(objServerResponse.responseText);
           }
       });
    });

    menuItemApplication.header.on('click', function() {
       Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: 'content/view_application.php',
           success: function(objServerResponse) {

               regionContent.update(objServerResponse.responseText);
           }
       });
    });
});
```

the file that is being loaded via Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function() {
        alert('from application view'); //is not executed
    }

    //Ext.onReady(function(){
    //    alert('from application view extjs'); //is not executed
    //}
</script>
<?php
echo 'this is the application view at ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the ajax response the onload event on the window has been already fired so the function won't be executed because the onload event won't be fired again. Try only with the alert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('from application view');
</script>
<?php
echo 'this is the application view at ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Browsers don't execute injected scripts in that way so you can try with something like:

```
var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText))
{
   eval(scripts[1]);
}
```

Comment: that's how I originally had it but it doesn't execute either, no errors in Firebug Net panel, it is as if javascript is just ignored, do I need to be using something other than responseText perhaps? but responseBody even makes the generated content from PHP not appear

Comment: Try to log the responseText in firebug with console.log and check if the script tag is present, because some libraries just remove script tags for security reasons

Comment: yes it shows the full script tag, I see it also in the net panel for the view_application.php ajax call in the response header, the full `<script...>...</script>` is there

Comment: same result in multiple browsers, javascript turned on of course, even if I type `sldkfjsdfkjs` in the javascript block there is no error, as if the whole block is just being ignored, yet I see it in the ajax response

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried passing `true` for the second param to [`Panel.load`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/Component.html#method-Ext.Component-update) (which happens to be the **loadScripts** option)?

```
regionContent.update(objServerResponse.responseText, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you call update with ext you just do 
update(string,true) and it will execute scripts contained within the string. However, ext core seems to lack this functionality, but there is no documentation for the update method (I had to search the actual code to confirm this.)

If you are using some regular EXT (like ext-all) you can simply add

```
regionContent.update(objServerResponse.responseText,true);
```

like this and it should eval the scripts. No dice for me, though - ext-all is too slow but I need eval functionality. I may have to hack EXT.