# Why would javascript eval work in chrome, safari, but in firefox only when firebug on?

Tags: ajax, firefox, extjs, firebug

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333326/why-doesnt-javascript-execute-in-php-file-loaded-with-ext-ajax-request/4333374#4333374) I was able to get javascript to execute when being loaded via an ExtJS AJAX call.

However, the following code does not work the same in all browsers (on mac):

- chrome: works, alert pops up
- safari: works, alert pops up
- firefox: works, *but only when Firebug is enabled*, when Firebug is not enabled, the script is ignored

**How can I get javascript to execute via AJAX call in Firefox without having Firebug installed?**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    var menuItemStart = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'panelStart',
        title: 'Start',
        html: 'This is the start menu item.',
        cls:'menuItem'
    });

    var menuItemApplication = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'panelApplication',
        title: 'Application',
        html: 'this is the application page',
        cls:'menuItem'
    });

    var regionMenu = new Ext.Panel({
        region:'west',
        split:true,
        width: 210,
        layout:'accordion',
        layoutConfig:{
            animate:true
        },
        items: [ menuItemStart, menuItemApplication ]
    });

    var regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'contentArea',
        region: 'center',
        padding:'10',
        autoScroll: true,
        html: 'this is the content'
    });

    new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ regionMenu, regionContent ]
    });

    menuItemStart.header.on('click', function() {
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'content/view_start.php',
            success: function(objServerResponse) {
                regionContent.update(objServerResponse.responseText);
            }
        });
    });

    menuItemApplication.header.on('click', function() {             
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'content/view_application.php',
            success: function(objServerResponse) {
                var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
                console.log(responseText);
                regionContent.update(responseText);
                var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
                while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
                    eval(scripts[1]);
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

The base that is being loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('inside application view');
</script>
<?php
echo 'this is the application view at ' . date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` is your culprit.

Whenever you're logging in JavaScript, it's a good idea to check if console exists before calling it's functions:

```
if(window.console) console.log('whatever');
```

That way, it will only execute when the console is available.

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(responseText);
```

this line seems problematic to me. `console` exists only when Firebug is on, so you'll have to comment it, or do some checking whether it exists before using it.

Comment: forgot that was in there :-), and useful to know that it causes problems in firefox, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if removing `console.log` fixed this for you, but please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333326/why-doesnt-javascript-execute-in-php-file-loaded-with-ext-ajax-request/4336919#4336919) regarding the `loadScripts` config also.