# How can I execute Javascript via ExtJS AJAX call without eval() as I can with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, eval

I would like to execute javascript in pages which I load via `Ext.Ajax.request`. To do this, I have to load the scripts and `eval()` them like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'content/view_application.php',
    success: function(objServerResponse) {
        var responseText = objServerResponse.responseText;
        regionContent.update(responseText);
        var scripts, scriptsFinder=/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]+)<\/script>/gi;
        while(scripts=scriptsFinder.exec(responseText)) {
            eval(scripts[1]);
        }
    }
});
```

With JQuery, however, I can have Javascript executed in pages which are called via AJAX without resorting to `eval()` like this:

```
function replaceContentOnClick(id, pageToLoad) {
    $('body').delegate(('#' + id), 'click', function(){
        $.get('content/' + pageToLoad, function(data) {
            $('#regionContent .x-panel-body').html(data);
        });
    });
}
```

**How is it that JQuery manages to execute the javascript in the loaded page without `eval()`? Is there a way to load the javascript without resorting to `eval()` in ExtJS as well?**

Comment: I can answer only your first question: jquery looks at the Content-Type http header and if it is `application/json` it will do the necessary conversion before invoking the `success` callback.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I wouldn't worry about the `eval` statement. I am aware that Douglas Crockford counsels against its use:

> eval is evil
>
> The eval function (and its relatives,
>   Function, setTimeout, and setInterval)
>   provide access to the JavaScript
>   compiler. This is sometimes necessary,
>   but in most cases it indicates the
>   presence of extremely bad coding. The
>   eval function is the most misused
>   feature of JavaScript.

(from http://www.jslint.com/lint.html)

Here he states that "This is sometimes necessary", and I would argue that your use is a valid one.

The JSON2.js library ([http://www.json.org](http://www.json.org/)) uses this command, and flags to JSLint that this is intended:

```
/*jslint evil: true */
```

Is there a particular reason that you would like to avoid its use?

Comment: +1, I agree (and very nearly wrote an answer similar to yours), but the advantage of my solution (well, jQuery's solution) is that it executes the statement in the global context, which eval doesn't do. (In many situations local is better, but I would think that for downloading scripts via AJAX, the solution nearly always needs to be global.)

Comment: I would like to avoid its use simply because it raises a security issue, and as you mentioned, Douglas Crockford identified it as a "bad part" of Javascript for this reason. I also assumed that executing javascript from within an AJAX call would be taken care of by other methods so that it is safer than calling a raw eval on script that was loaded from any source.

Answer (score 1):

Well, go to the jQuery source (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) and Ctrl+F for `globalEval: function`. This is the function which runs JavaScript. You'll see it actually adds script tags into the DOM. As for extJS, I don't know. Try searching in their source code for "script" or 'script' to see if they insert script tags anywhere in a similar way. Or you could just implement your own `globalEval`.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding like a [broken record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333771/why-would-javascript-eval-work-in-chrome-safari-but-in-firefox-only-when-firebu/4336948#4336948), please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333326/why-doesnt-javascript-execute-in-php-file-loaded-with-ext-ajax-request/4336919#4336919) regarding the `loadScripts` config.  You should consider sticking to the same question when it's just a follow-up to what you've already asked, rather than starting brand new questions.